# Store mongodb data in compressed format

Tags: mongodb, compression

I am using mongodb to store raw HTML data of web pages using scrapy framework. In one day of web scraping 25GB disk space is filled up. Is there a way to store raw data in compressed format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing built in for compression. Some operating systems offer disk/file compression, but if you want more control, I'd suggest you compress it using a library for whatever programming language you're using and manually control the compression.

For example, NodeJs offers simple convenience methods for this: http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_examples

#### 3.0 Update

If you choose to switch to the new storage engine WiredTiger which ships with 3.0, you can choose between several types of compression as documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/storage/#storage-wiredtiger-compression). Of course, you'll want to test this change in production workloads to find if the additional CPU utilization is worth the compression received.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506897/how-do-i-gzip-compress-a-string-in-python

Comment: @binit No: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-164?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: @binit -Why wouldn't you want to compress the data with Python?

Comment: there is no facility in mongodb as per today. the recommended way is to compress it client side and write it as a binary field. f.ex use somethink like gzip to compress it before writing it.

Comment: You can try looking at TokuMX. They do compression on mongodb dataset and also replace the BTree storage engine with a (seemingly) better fractal tree datastructure. http://tokutek.com/products/tokumx-for-mongodb

Answer (score 7):

Starting with [2.8 version of Mongo, you can use compression](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.8/release-notes/2.8/#storage-engines-pluggable-api-improved-concurrency-document-level-locking-with-compression). You will have 3 levels of compression with WiredTiger engine, mmap (which is default in 2.6 does not provide compression):

- None
- [snappy](https://code.google.com/p/snappy/) (by default)
- [zlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib)

Here is an example of how much space will you be able to save for 16 GB of data:

[image]

data is taken from [this](http://comerford.cc/wordpress/2014/11/12/mongodb-2-8-new-wiredtiger-storage-engine-adds-compression/?utm_source=dbweekly&utm_medium=email) article.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your string like this to compress it: myhtml.encode('zlib')

Comment: myhtml.encode('zlib') doest always generate unicode, which causes problems when inserting into mongoDB.